# How to convert OgrGML to Oracle gml

Tags: qgis, ogr, oracle-dbms, gml

OgrGML and OracleGML format are not the same, I want to edit the parcel on QGIS which getting from OracleGML  format.

Is there any way to covert OgrGML to OracleGML and vise versa? (OracleGML format the geometry coordinates x and y separates by comma (,) but the OgrGML x,y coordinates separated by space.)

Comment: can you include a sample of each geometry for us. GML provides a cs and ts attribute to specify a separator for the coordinates and tuples

Answer (score 1):

Well the GML 1.0 and 2.0 standards use a comma to separate ordinates and a space to separate points, like this:

```
<gml:coordinates>0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100 0,0</gml:coordinates>
```

You can change that via the cs and ts attributes ...

The GML 3.1.1 standard however uses this notation:

```
<gml:posList srsDimension="2">0 0 100 0 100 100 0 100 0 0</gml:posList>
```

Is this what you observe ?